# Windows 10 login screen glitch

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen

My windows 10 login screen is not revealed easily. I've had this problem for awhile now where the welcome screen with the clock keeps jumping up and down out of rhythm. And to lift it up and reveal the password screen, I have to click and press space key a few times.

Is there some way I can fix this. Thanks.

**Update**

I have an Asus X550L notebook. I have noticed that my keyboard is malfunctioning now. But this problem was present before any major problem with the keyboard.

The screen with the clock that slides up and reveals the password inputs or the image password screen? It doesn't slide up in one go. It tries to go up and then falls down. And keeps doing this up and down motion.

Comment: What type of computer do you have? Have you checked that the keyboard and mouse are functioning properly? Have you tried connecting a DIFFERENT keyboard and mouse to the computer? What do you mean by "jumping up and down out of rhythm"? Have you checked for Windows updates?

Comment: Along with what music suggested, have you ran a virus scan of some sort recently?

Comment: Hi thanks. I updated my question with more details. Is there no known glitch in windows 10 login screen? Is it just my keyboard?